# How to use orderby for Arraylist?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, arraylist

I need to fetch the data for an arraylist in descending order (Date). For this we are using orderby feature of lambda expression. But while doing this I am facing a problem. In case of null date it returns error. Error is "Input string not a correct DateTime".

Example:

```
var comnData = ch.Request.NsType.SomeCollection.Cast<MiscType>().Select(x => x.Data).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Date)).OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Date, @"dMyyyy", culture));
```

If I don't use where clause it throws an error. If I use then I am unable to fetch data having null Date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ternary operator

```
OrderByDescending(x => x.Date!=null? DateTime.ParseExact(x.Date, @"dMyyyy", culture):DateTime.MinValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check for null and return some default date in that case (like '1970-01-01') in your OrderByDescending lambda expression.